# How to get to the file explorer in android studio

Tags: android, file, android-emulator

Okay I don't know how to get to the file explorer in android studio. I already tried searching stack overflow and I found the same question I am asking but the solution there didn't work. So with screen shots could someone tell me how to get to the file explorer?

Answer (score 8):

For Android Studio 0.8.6, go to `Tools` > `Android` > `Android Device Monitor` in the main menu, to bring up the Android Device Monitor in a separate window. There you will find what amounts a set of Eclipse perspectives, notably the DDMS perspective, which has the File Explorer view.

Comment: For some reason when I try and open that up, it asks me where the android sdk is and when I put in the directory, it says: "C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\hprof-conv.exe not present".

Comment: @user3843164: Make sure that you are on the latest "Build-tools" and "Platform-tools" in the SDK Manager. I seem to recall that `hprof-conv.exe` was missing in the days after Google I|O, but AFAIK that has since been repaired.

Comment: As soon as you start your app it tells you it needs to close the DDMS, so you're left with a basic cut down version of DDMS built into android studio.

Comment: debugging and ADM don't go together.. one of them needs to be finished.

Answer (score 4):

From the main menu go to:
`Tools` > `Android` > `Android Device Monitor`

then from the `Android Device Monitor`´s menu:

`Window` > `Show View` > choose: `File Explorer`

[image]