# Where on Earth is the File Explorer Window in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Guys at JetBrains must love to hide the most common tools. Why can't the Android Studio be at least as good as the old eclipse plugin.

Just where on Earth did the file explorer window go?

I've already read:

- [File Explorer in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628670/file-explorer-in-android-studio)
- [How to get to the file explorer in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354707/how-to-get-to-the-file-explorer-in-android-studio)

But this is all I can get:

[image]

Where is the file explorer tab supposed to be found? When I clicked the Android Device Monitor button it said it was already shown. But now it gives me a "Failed to create the Java VM" error that disconnects the device, and a few seconds later it reconnects again.

Using Android Studio v1.1.0

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941437/android-studio-error-android-device-monitor

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941437/android-studio-error-android-device-monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @Lipi's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25159856.

The .ini file was trying to give the monitor too much memory, and reducing it solved the issue. That file is in the Android SDK folder, it's not inside AS.

Android Studio **does not currently show the file explorer as a tab in the IDE**, it just uses the SDK's and opens it in a separate window.